Having trouble with Odoo 17 action.post
Error:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1122, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1461, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1166, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1182, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1351, in parse_response
    return u.close()
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 668, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])


xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n 
File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line
147, in xmlrpc_2\n    response = self._xmlrpc(service)\n  File
"/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 128,
in _xmlrpc\n    return xmlrpc.client.dumps((result,),
methodresponse=1, allow_none=False)\n  File
"/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 981, in dumps\n    data =
m.dumps(params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line
514, in dumps\n    dump(v, write)\n  File
"/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 536, in __dump\n   
f(self, value, write)\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py",
line 540, in dump_nil\n    raise TypeError("cannot marshal None unless
allow_none is enabled")\nTypeError: cannot marshal None unless
allow_none is enabled\n'>

Hello, in 16 version everything worked fine but now when executing this command:
models.execute_kw(odoo_db_name, uid, odoo_key, 'account.move', 'action_post', [new_invoice_id])
Although the invoice gets created goes from Draft to Posted and I get the new invoice DV and the pdf link is visible. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Maybe there should be a return statement?
I found that the post is causing the issue, but don't know what is wrong with it.
And yes I tried setting the allow_none to enabled, but that isn't the issue, the issue is with validating the invoice or in other words with returning it probably

Are you sure that's the call raising the error? Because atleast since Odoo v15 account.move.action_post() is returning False.

Yes I am sure, I also just updated probably a false solution which works. As I mentioned earlier everything was working, I just got the error, although the invoice was created.

I possibly found an issue, it could be an Odoo problem, changed the line:
models.execute_kw(odoo_db_name, uid, odoo_key, 'account.move', 'action_post', [new_invoice_id])

to:
models.execute_kw(odoo_db_name, uid, odoo_key,'account.move', 'write', [[new_invoice_id], {'state': 'posted'}])


That could lead to missing a lot of checks built into action_post or rather _post. My advice: don't solve it like this.

Well I haven’t found another solution any advice would be appreciated!

Because as I already mentioned every check was running good, I also have additional check regarding the invoice, which make sure that the invoice is according to all the requirements that are needed, just the action_post is bugging, although the invoice is being formed and everything runs fine.
